# Vibration Mode missing in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-vibration, missing-features

I created a simple and small volume control app. Now I am trying to test it on lower android versions in android studio emulator, But the vibration mode is missing. I brought the ring volume seekbar to 0 from phone settings and it was suppose to go to vibrate mode but DnD is turning on. I created new app and only execute setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) or setRingerMode(1), But still no vibration mode it goes to dnd. But it works fine on Android 13 api 33. Anyone have any idea what would be wrong? I am new to Android.

I have searched on internet but couldnt find any solution. Downloaded android studio again and installed it again, updated emulator. But none of it works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.